# Cannot Delete File on Carousel

Tags: c#, carousel, uwp

How do I delete files with certain extensions? For example: .pdf

I try this code:

```
StorageFolder library = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync("library", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
BookAudio hapusmajalah = this.carousel.SelectedItem as BookAudio;
try
                        {
if(hapusmajalah.Name == hapusmajalah.Name + ".pdf")
{
    StorageFile filepdf = await library.GetFileAsync(hapusmajalah.Name + ".pdf");

                            await filepdf.DeleteAsync();
}

                            this.carousel.SelectedItem = carousel.Items[0];
                            await this.getContent();

                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            this.carousel.SelectedItem = carousel.Items[0];
                            this.getContent();
                        }
                    }));
}
```

BookAudio Class:

```
class BookAudio
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    }
```

but not successfully removed. If not using the if, then the file has been successfully removed. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the path.getextension.

The references are:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
```

And the main code would be:

```
#region //Remove files with the extensions in the list.
    public static void deleteFileExtensions(List<string> fileExtensionsToRemove, string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            /*Get the extension by splitting by the final period.*/
            string tocompare = Path.GetExtension(filepath);
            /*For every element in the list, if one of the extensions matches the file extension, delete*/
            fileExtensionsToRemove.ForEach(x => { if (tocompare.Contains(x)) File.Delete(filepath); });
        }
        catch(IOException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }
    }
    #endregion
```

Then you could call it like:

```
deleteFileExtensions(File.ReadAllLines("ExtensionsToDelete.txt").ToList(), "yourFilePath");
```

Comment: what the mean of "yourFilePath"? 
In my project the file on "library" StorageFolder